# reflect: Is it possible to get the underlying typed type information?

Tags: reflection, go

I'm porting a program from [`go/ast`](http://golang.org/pkg/go/ast) to [`reflect`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect). In order to pass the tests I need to get not only the top type information but also the underlying type if the underlying type is not built-in.

In the example below, is it possible for a program to know that the underlying type of main.T is main.TT?

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

func main() {
    type TT int
    type T TT

    x := T(0)
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(x))
}
```

Output:

```
 main.T
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying type of `main.T` is `int`, not `main.TT`. The reflect package has no knowledge that `main.T` was declared with `main.TT`.

Here's what the [specification has to say about underlying types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types):

> Each type T has an underlying type: If T is one of the predeclared boolean, numeric, or string types, or a type literal, the corresponding underlying type is T itself. Otherwise, T's underlying type is the underlying type of the type to which T refers in its type declaration.
>
> ```
> type T1 string
> type T2 T1
> type T3 []T1
> type T4 T3
> ```
>
> The underlying type of string, T1, and T2 is string. The underlying type of []T1, T3, and T4 is []T1.